# Format increment variable output in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm stuck on a rather simple problem with the increment of a variable that gets printed out as consecutive strings to a file.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

_SesT=`date +%Y\/%m\/%d\ %H\-%M\-%S` 

n="0"

Execution_IT(){

    while read $3
    do
        ((n++))
        printf $n 
    done < ExecLog.txt

}

echo "test" && echo $_SesT
printf "Execution $(Execution_IT) Started $_SesT\r\n" >> ExecLog.txt
```

The problem is that the output gets formatted like this:

```
Execution  Started 2016/02/08 19-06-44
Execution 1 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-44
Execution 12 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-44
Execution 123 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-45
Execution 1234 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-45
Execution 12345 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-45
Execution 123456 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-46...
```

... instead of:

```
Execution 1 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-44
Execution 2 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-44
Execution 3 Started 2016/02/08 19-06-45...
```

This is the most working version I got to after trying `cut -d`; `awk`; `sed`; and even C-like syntax `for` loop. There was a version very similar to this with `while read line`, but the output was exactly the same. Any suggestions will be well-appreciated.

Comment: where do you call `Execution_IT`? and what is `Session_IT`?

Comment: did you mean to recalculate the `date` at every line, or just once at the beginning of the script?

Comment: I copied over the wrong func name at the bottom, which is pretty much the same. Now i call Execution_IT. I also wanted to print out d/t at every line, so yes that is as it should be.

Comment: BTW, if you're targeting a bash with the `%()T` builtin printf string (4.3, I think?), you could get date and time **much** more efficiently.

Comment: ...and reading your file in a subshell to count executions seems *ridiculously* inefficient. A one-line file with advisory locking for updates would give you constant-time performance, as opposed to slowing down as you have more log contents.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to accomplish and how you want to do it.  I don't see in your code how multiple lines would be printed.  There is only one `printf` printing "Execution  Started" at the end of the code, and it's not in a loop.  (The `printf`'s in the function call output on the same line.)  How do you get multiple lines reading "Execution Started"?  Are you running this script over and over?

Comment: @e0k The `printf` in the `while` loop...?

Comment: @e0k, eh? the `printf` in the loop is, well, **in the loop**. That it's in a loop in a function called in your subshell doesn't stop it from being called once per line in the file.

Comment: BTW, what's with the `read $3`? You don't **have** any variable name passed to the function as `$3` (as when you call the function it's with no arguments at all), and if you expect `read` to be **setting** the value in `$3`... well, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: on every execution of another script this one records the start time to a text file. so yes this is ran over and over(and since this is a short example of what im trying to do- yes this one im doing manually)

Comment: Can it be run more than once at a time? If so, you're prone to race conditions (you could have two runs both thinking they're Execution 100, for instance).

Comment: $3 is the position of the numeric value i want to print as 1, 2 ,3 on separate lines instead of 1, 12, 123 and so on

Comment: @NiU, each function call has its own argument list. When you call `Execution_IT`, all those variables -- `$1`, `$2`, `$3` -- are empty unless you pass the function arguments. If you're telling it you want to read the third column of the file... well, simply put, that's not the right syntax to do so; perhaps you're thinking of `awk`.

Comment: ...but `$3` doesn't mean column-3 in bash; it's only awk where it means that.

Comment: There is an issue with a delegation of tasks here. You're asking a script to somehow know how many times it has been called before, rather than have the script that launches it maintain a tally.  A rethink of your design could simplify many of your issues.

Comment: @e0k, there are circumstances under which I can see the decision to put that on the callee side of the interface as reasonable -- for instance, if the launch is mediated by xargs or parallel. On the other hand, those circumstances make the specifics of the approach used here intrinsically prone to race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are only printing *one* line to the file "ExecLog.txt", and specifically, one last line is appended.

All that line contains is the count of lines in the file and the date.
That could be done better like this:

```
_logfile="ExecLog.txt"

n="$(wc -l <"$_logfile")"      ### count the number of lines in the log file.

_SesT="$(date +%Y\/%m\/%d\ %H\-%M\-%S)"   ### get time just before it is used.

echo "test $_SesT $_logfile"
printf "Execution %s Started %s\r\n" "$n" "$_SesT" | tee -a "$_logfile"
```

---

If you must have a loop for each line to do something else, understand that the variable n does not lose its value on exiting the function. So, it could be used later in the script.

Print it in the line to be added to the logfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

_logfile="ExecLog.txt"

Execution_IT(){
    n="0"
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        echo "loop $n"
        ((n++))
        # do something with $line.
    done < "$_logfile"
}

Execution_IT                              ### execute the loop.
_SesT="$(date +%Y\/%m\/%d\ %H\-%M\-%S)"   ### get time just before it is used.

echo "test time=$_SesT and count=$n"
printf "Execution %s Started %s\r\n" "$n" "$_SesT" >> "$_logfile"
```

Understand that this is just a simple example that does not have any control on race conditions. Some other script may write a line to the logfile between this script has counted the lines and just before the appended line is added. In that case, the count will be wrong. Or several copies of this script running could have the same (incorrect) count.

Comment: this is exactly what i was trying to accomplish. regarding your first example i never thought of using **tee** even just for the sake of testing. the second example does the job perfectly and im just not skilled enough to think of that. regarding multiple executions- im avoiding that with a condition statement beforehand to deny the execution of any  other script until the ongoing one has finished, so thats ok. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf` needs a newline:

```
printf "%d\n" "$n"
```

or, alternatively,

```
echo "$((++n))"
```

Comment: `$n`, not `"$n"`? Do we want string-splitting and glob expansion here? (Granted, numeric IFS values aren't common, but they *could* happen).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, we don't want them here ;)

Comment: I think we definitely want string splitting here. Another thing that just didn't work was something like this:
front=${texttext{$back}} and calling $back but that didnt happen as well. Somebody just suggested that to me.

Comment: @NiU, huh? "String splitting", in this context, means that if `IFS=0`, and your `$n` is `301`, you would print `3` and `1` on two different lines, instead of `301` on one line. I can't conceive of why you would want that.

Comment: @NiU I think you're talking about something else here, and no that double indirection doesn't work.